# How to put a ListView in a Fragment

Tags: android, listview, fragment

I had a good ListView, but now I added Fragments, now my Code doesn't work in the onCreateMenu...

How to make my ListView back?

So here's my code:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View myFragmentView;
        Bundle b = getArguments();
        int Nr = b.getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER);
        if (Nr == 0) {
            myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layoutexample, container, false);
        } else {
            myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.another_layout_example, container, false);
        }
        return myFragmentView;
    }
```

I don't understand, where to put my code (for example if I want a ListView)!

Can I use something similar to the inflater?

Please help, as a beginner I only understand half of the information, Google Developers gives me...

This is my ListView:

```
public class Home extends ListActivity {
ListView listView;
static final String[] Liste = {"a", "b", "c"};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setTitle("CalcPlus");

    listView = getListView();

    listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.text, Liste) {
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

            String item = getItem(position);

            TextView subTitleView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.subtitle);
            subTitleView.setText("Subtitle of " + item);

            return view;
        }
    });
}
}
```

That's the list_item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dp" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text=""
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textSize="22dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/subtitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text=""
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:textStyle="normal" />

</LinearLayout>
```

---

Here's the example.xml (they both look the same):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: There is a class called ListFragment may save your time.

Answer (score 0):

After having inflated your view, you can add :

```
ListView listView = myFragmentView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
listView.setAdapter(....);
```

Edit : I didn't know the id you set to your ListView. Replace `android.R.id.list` by `R.id.listView1`

Comment: I get Type `mismatch: cannot convert from View to ListView`

Comment: Post the view you are inflating please : R.layout.layoutexample & R.layout.another_layout_example.